# Overlay own content into a fullscreen game/application in windows - like fraps (fps monitors)

Tags: c++, c, directx, direct3d

I am not much into graphics programming yet but I have the desire to write a tool which is able to overlay data into a running 3d game without causing trouble to the game.

A good example is fraps, a FPS monitoring tool that can display the FPS in about any game/application without causing instability.

I guess it's about hooking into the direct3d calls, however I would like to know which way is the best to choose (for compatibility) and if there is any source coude I could start with.
It should be C/C++.

Comment: Such questions are asked again and again, I think there should be enough to read through on Stackoverflow and the internet. Afaik fraps doing alot of magic to achieve their overlay and it doesn't suffices to only hook in the direct3d calls. The topic is not as simple as it looks.

Comment: I have seen several questions but they did not really help me.  
The solutions were not "broad" enough or seemed too "hacky".  
My hope was that there might be an open source project that has such a solution made in a compatible way where I could get a kickstart.

Comment: Windows doesn't provide any supported way of doing this. As Gnietschow says Fraps has do a lot of magic in order to work, which another way of saying "hacky".

Comment: More importantly, why do people keep wanting to remake FRAPS when there's FRAPS...

Comment: I did not state that I want to remake it. I want to use the same compatible approach, that's all.
I have a completely different app in mind.